# Update two documents in different collections in ArangoDB?

Tags: arangodb

I have two collections: **users** and **tweets**. I would like to know the AQL query that allows me to insert a new tweet and at the same time update the total tweets from a user.

In the **users** collection there is a document like:
{
_key:"user1",
total_tweets: 0
}

In the **tweets** collection there are multiple "tweet" documents like:
{
_key:"tweet1",
from_user:"users/user1"
}

How can I insert a new tweet and at the same time update the total_tweets in the user?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are expecting a solution that uses the trigger functionality of SQL database.

However, ArangoDB does not offer trigger functionality.
So, to update the number of total_tweets in users collection after a new tweet is inserted, there are two solutions.

1. Combine the "insert tweet query" and "update tweet count query" into one big query, and every time when you are inserting a tweet, execute this big query.
2. Separate these two actions into two queries, execute them one by one in code, and use a transaction to ensure the ACID property of the database while executing multiple queries.

Answer (score 0):

Once you `INSERT` to one collection, you can use the `NEW` document to get the result of that insert (grabbing `_id` or `_key`).  Then you can run another `INSERT/UPDATE/UPSERT/REPLACE` on a ***different*** collection.  You cannot modify the same collection twice.

The [documentation](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.9/aql/operations-insert.html) talks about how to use `OLD` and `NEW` but doesn't seem to mention that updating multiple collections only works with `INSERT`, not `UPSERT` or `REPLACE` (throws an `"OLD set multiple times"` error).

However, if I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to update an integer (`total_tweets`) after inserting the tweet.  This is the territory of [transactions](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/transactions-transaction-invocation.html), which are handled with code, not through AQL.